# Next Link component is reloading the page

Tags: hyperlink, components

When I run the 'next run start' command, the links work correctly. However, when I deploy to Firebase Hosting (Firebase Deploy) the links do not work correctly in the app, updating the browser with each page accessed.

Does anyone have a similar problem and resolved it?

My version of next: 13.4.19
Firebase CLI: 12.5.4

Already tried:

install firebase;
update next;
Delete the .next folder and run npm run build